# Sqlite insert statement will not put a record in the table

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, insert

Everything in this function seems to work as expected, just no record actually shows up in the database table.  If I enter the sql directly through the Firefox sqlite manager plugin, the record appears just fine.  Probably something frustratingly stupid, any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)buttonInsertRecord:(id)sender
{
    // initializing db file access
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"KJV.sqlite"];

    // testing to see if database was found
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        // database not found
        labelStatus.text = @"database not found";
    }
    else
    {
        // database not found
        labelStatus.text = @"database found";
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlite3 *dbPointer;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath.UTF8String, &dbPointer) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_id) VALUES ('testuser', null);"];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbPointer, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            labelStatus.text = @"added";
        }
        else
        {
            labelStatus.text = @"failed";
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(dbPointer);
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem comes up often (though I can't find a duplicate at the moment). You can't write to the read-only resource bundle (on a real device). You need to copy the database to an appropriate, writable area of your app's sandbox and then work with that copy of the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    //your database is not writable because its in the bundle.
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"KJV.sqlite"];
```

if you want a readable/writable database, you can do this:

```
    - (void) createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded 
    {   
        BOOL success;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databasename.sqlite"];
        NSLog(@"writableDBPath == %@",writableDBPath);
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath])
        {
            NSLog(@"Database already exist");
        }
        else 
        {
            NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databasename.sqlite"];
            success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
            if (!success) 
                NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
```

and heres how you add your data

```
- (void) addToDatabase
{
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databasename.sqlite"];

        if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &mDatabase_update) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Insert into table 
             .
             .
             .
             .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I didn't know you couldn't write to the bundled database, though in retrospect I guess it makes sense.  So, essentially I need to create a new database when the app is first run on the local phone with all the 'volatile' ongoing user data and that database will be there until the app is uninstalled?  Thanks again for taking the time to answer.